# Codeigniter not running class definitions - PHP or Apache config problem

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, server-configuration, php-ini

I just uploaded working site files to a new server which I know is likely to have php/apache config problems as I've had to work with the server admin to sort them out to get this far.

When I visit the the site I don't get any errors just a blank page. I know that the default controller is being run as if I echo something outside the class it gets printed but the same inside the class constructor does nothing.

I expect this to be related to a server config issue as I have had the site working locally and live on another server for over a year but it is possible that there is something wrong with the codeigniter setup.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Check in your php.in that display_errors = On and error_reporting = E_ALL . It would help if you could see the error message. Also, check your error logs

Comment: They are on. There is no error message.

Comment: maybe look inside .htaccess file. some redirects, rewrite rules...

Comment: the rewrites are correct. there could be a problem with mod_rewrite though

Comment: tested mod_rewrite and it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the new server had a slightly upgraded version of PHP which required me to update Codeigniter. After the update it worked fine.

Strange that it didn't produce any errors though